# Odroid X installing ROS

Tags: robotic-arm, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I am trying to use odroid X to install ROS. Operating system is Ubuntu 12.04 from Linaro 12.08.

I have tried follow the steps from http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu and when i type sudo apt-get update, I got the following error:

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I am not sure whats the problem, will appreciate the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43600/odroid-x-installing-ros/) by [halfstopper](https://answers.ros.org/users/2417/halfstopper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try to Follow the instructions to install from source found here:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source

---

Originally posted by [ggamble22](https://answers.ros.org/users/2768/ggamble22/) with karma: 61 on 2012-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-28**:
To explain the reason why you need to do an installation from source: the Odroid-X has an ARM processor and the ROS debian packages are only built for i386 and amd64.